# How to get nuget repository path in msbuild macro?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I have a question regarding the nuget repository path.
So in `NuGet.config` I have

```
<config>
  <add key="repositoryPath" value="./packages" />
</config>
```

Is it possible to access this value in `.vcxproj` file? And I would like to access it directly using msbuld macros like `${SolutionDir}` or `${ProjectDir}`.

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue? Actually, you cannot get what you want from nuget.config file by msbuild. And from the point of designing this file, msbuild property cannot obtain the keys in the file `nuget.config`. Unless you manually define the value of this key in the vcxproj file.

Answer (score 0):

`xxx.vcxproj` and `nuget.config` are two different files and they cannot visit each other differently, after all, their role is not within the same area.

The `nuget.config` files works for the operation of the nuget packages while the `xxx.vcxproj` file works for build process. SO there are two different fields of files.

**So** there is no such msbuild property to get that value.

**Update**

You might say something like `hintpath`.That is the dll's relative path. And the reference objects of `vcxproj` and `repositoryPath` are different.

**When** you install a nuget package by `packages.config` nuget management format, nuget will first search the path of `repositoryPath` and know where the nuget packages should be installed. Then, nuget will install packages under that path.

**Immediately afterwards**, vs will center on the `vcxproj` file, look for the dll in this path, and refer to the dll in the nuget at that address in a relative path. Therefore, what you see in `vcxproj` is not the value of `repositoryPath`, but `vcxproj` as the center, find the relative path of the `repositoryPath`.

**You should note that** these are all nuget did. And MSBuild does not have the folder address of the nuget packages, it only has the address referenced by the specific dll, and msbuild can only receive the result of the nuget.

It is true that you will find the referenced address in msbuild and mistakenly think this is the `repositoryPath`. It is very intuitive, but they are not the same because they use different reference objects. The `repositoryPath` is centered on the `nuget.config` file, and the path on `vcxproj` is centered on `vcxproj`, and they are all relative paths. The `repositoryPath` is the folder address, and `vcxproj` is the address of the specific dll, so there is no way to get it through msbuild.

**And** you cannot make sure that `nuget.config` and `vcxproj` files are in the same folder, and from the design of `nuget.config`, it should be set on the solution level or above. Therefore, for them who use relative paths, capturing becomes empty talk.

Comment: Well, the `vcxproj` file contains references to nuget packages. There is a msbuild target called something like ensurenugetpackages and the packages are listed in `vcxproj` file with the path to the repository so it would make sense the `repositoryPath` is available in a macro variable. But this all could be generated by the NuGet Package Manager so you may be right.